# How to prevent picking ONLY the DAY from the mat-datepicker?

Tags: angular, html, datepicker, angular-material, material-design

I need to allow users to **pick only year and month**, without picking the actual day of the month.

Can anyone help out ???

**---------------------------------------------------------**

Given Stack is Angular 5 and Material Design 5.2.5

I **cannot** upgrade Material Design to 6 (where the API easily enables this)

Comment: This part from the documentation for example? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#watching-the-views-for-changes-on-selected-years-and-months

Comment: this is for Material Design v6, where they have a very nice solution for this problem, I need to remain on v5. Thanks anyways

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that part from your comment. What is the purpose of that the user can only select year and month? Maybe you should mask the date format to MM/YYYY.

Comment: Yup, project demands month view following a year view pick with no day view following that.....

Comment: I would recommend this package. It is really flexible and the requested functions are included. I'd prefer using this compared to material stuff. https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/ (Watching changes of selected year and selected month part)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about mat-datepicker but here's a JS datepicker if you can use it. It's set on MM-YYYY.

Here's the HTML

```
<input class="form-control" id="date" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="date" placeholder="MM-YYYY">
```

And here's the Javascript. You have to include bootstrap-datepicker.min.js and bootstrap-datepicker3.css which you can google for.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date"]');
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
            format: "mm-yyyy",
            startView: "months", 
            minViewMode: "months",
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,

    })
})
```

Comment: Angular - Material Design, mat-datepicker - hence js cannot help out here while maintaining best practice